# Memcached on Windows (wamp) with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached, wamp

I'm developing locally with laravel under wamp, i want to use memcached (not memcache) and after hours and days of searching i could find only memcache for windows but no memcached.

laravel support only memcached, and the trick `$memcached = new memcache` doesn't work like in other frameworks
if i try to run a page that contains caching code the debugger will throw an error like

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) HELP

Class 'Memcached' not found
```

[image]

i'm struggling with this since a long time i really need to stimulate load speed with cache as close as web servers locally (without installing vagrant)

Comment: try this (not sure if it will work but looks promising)? http://shiki.me/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/

Comment: @clonerworks what you see in my screenshot is actually laravel recognizing memcache as "not memcached" i installed memcache as in all those articles like the one you gave me, this is sad that all people are saying "how to install memcached" while it is memcache in their articles (memcache dll)

Comment: What version of WAMPServer/Apache/PHP are you running?

Comment: wamp 2.5 ,
apache 2.4.9 ,
php 5.5.12 ,
mySql 5.6.17